# Trying to install pycaret on anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, libraries, pycaret

I am trying to install pycaret on anaconda but I keep getting this error.

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure
  
  × Encountered error while trying to install package.
  ╰─> numpy
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Can someone please help me with that?

I tried using multiple prompts:
conda install -c conda-forge pycaret
pip install pycaret

I tried to install numpy seperately and got was able to do that sucessfuly but I got this message:

Collecting numpy
Using cached numpy-1.24.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (19.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
smop 0.41b0 requires networkx, which is not installed.
smop 0.41b0 requires ply, which is not installed.
smop 0.41b0 requires pytest, which is not installed.
smop 0.41b0 requires scipy, which is not installed.
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.1

and so I installed all these packages and reinstalled numpy again. Afterwards, I tried to install pycaret again but the same error appeared. Keeping in mind that I have a mac laptop.